Why WP CLI command is not visible in VIP CLI
I have registered the command like below and pushed this to VIP's development environment but when I try to execute this command from VIP CLI it throws an error.
Note: on local this command is being registered and working correctly.
WP_CLI::add_command( 'add-tabindex-aria-label', array( $this, 'add_tabindex_arialabel_handler' ) );

Error: 'add-tabindex-aria-label' is not a registered wp command. See 'wp help' for available commands. 

And what full command are you trying on VIP?

This needs more context, like where you added this code and how you are loading/including the respective file.

vip @id.env -- wp add-tabindex-aria-label post_id --url=abc.go-vip.net/abc

Thanks vancoder swisspidy I figured out the solution, the issue was with the multisite on which I am trying to run the command was under maintenance and after removing it from maintenance it worked.
